Is it possible to compose two independent events given this condition?
Let's say we have some set of independent events $E=\{A_1,A_2,..,A_n\}$. We can define event $X$ as combined in any way (via operations of intersection and complement) events from subset $S_X\subset E$. Also we can define event $Y$ as combined in any way (via operations of intersection and complement) events from subset $S_Y\subset E$. Do set $E$ and subsets $S_X$ and $S_Y$ exist for which it is possible to define these two events $X$ and $Y$ such that

$X$ and $Y$ are independent
$S_X\cap S_Y$ is not empty and contains not only events with probability $0$ or $1$

I guess it is not possible but I would like to be sure.

What is each $A_i=\emptyset$?

@geetha290krm then $S_X\cap S_Y$ can contain only $\emptyset$ and that is forbidden by the 2nd requirement

Flip three coins (fair and independent). Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i^\text{th}$ coin is heads, $1\le i\le 3$.
Let $X$ be the event that coins numbered one and two show the same face, and let $Y$ be the event that coins numbered two and three show the same face. N this means $S_X=\{1,2\}$ and $S_Y=\{2,3\}$.
$$
X=(A_1\cap A_2)\cup (\overline{A_1}\cap\overline{A_2})
\\
Y=(A_2\cap A_3)\cup (\overline{A_2}\cap\overline{A_3})
.$$
$X\cap Y$ is the event that all three coins show the same face. There are two ways this can happen, all heads or tails, both with probability $1/8$, so $P(X\cap Y)=1/8+1/8=1/4$. Since $X$ and $Y$ both have probability $1/2$, this shows that $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$, hence $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Oh, indeed, it's possible! It is interesting because events $X$ and $Y$  have some connection (event $A_2$) but nevertheless they are independent. Actually I was wondering if it is possible. Thank you for such a nice example Mike!
